# On Conditional Jensen Inequality Hypothesis

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lp-spaces, conditional-expectation, jensen-inequality

**
**Conditional Jensen Inequality**

Let $X$ be in $L^1$, and $\mathcal{G}$ a sigma-algebra of the space and $\phi$ a convex function. Then, $\mathbb E(\phi(X)|\mathcal{G}) \geq \phi(\mathbb E(X|\mathcal{G}))$.

**

Instead of requiring $X$ to be in $L^1$, can we weaken the hypothesis and just require $\mathbb E(\phi(X)|\mathcal{G})< \infty$?

Comment: did u see my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3624600/birkhoff-averages-convergence/3640204#3640204)? I saw you put a bounty on the question

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ is not in $L^1$, the RHS of the inequality is not defined. Suppose for example that $X$ is Cauchy distributed and that $\sigma(X)$ and $\mathcal{G}$ are independent.